# How to convert tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.BatchDataset to a numpy array?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, keras, tensorflow2.0, image-recognition

I am having an image dataset as

```
|-Train
| |-Defective
  | |-images
| |-Not_Defective
  | |-images
```

I preprocessed these images using the following function

```
dir='../input/railwaytrackv4/Dataset _ Railway Track Fault Detection-20210713T183411Z-001/Dataset _ Railway Track Fault Detection/Train'
train_data=tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(directory=dir,
                                                        labels='inferred',
                                                        batch_size=32,
                                                        image_size=(256, 256))
```

It gave output as `Found 1469 files belonging to 2 classes.`

And
`type(train_data)` = `tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.BatchDataset`

How to convert this `train_data` to a numpy array?

UPDATE:

I tried

```
for x, y in train_data:
   x = x.numpy()
   y = y.numpy()
```

But it gave the following as the output

```
2021-11-01 08:48:15.079479: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:185] None of the MLIR Optimization Passes are enabled (registered 2)
2021-11-01 08:48:25.085070: I tensorflow/core/kernels/data/shuffle_dataset_op.cc:175] Filling up shuffle buffer (this may take a while): 250 of 11760
2021-11-01 08:48:35.132351: I tensorflow/core/kernels/data/shuffle_dataset_op.cc:175] Filling up shuffle buffer (this may take a while): 558 of 11760
2021-11-01 08:48:45.122079: I tensorflow/core/kernels/data/shuffle_dataset_op.cc:175] Filling up shuffle buffer (this may take a while): 843 of 11760
2021-11-01 08:48:55.135867: I tensorflow/core/kernels/data/shuffle_dataset_op.cc:175] Filling up shuffle buffer (this may take a while): 1160 of 11760
2021-11-01 08:49:05.080678: I tensorflow/core/kernels/data/shuffle_dataset_op.cc:175] Filling up shuffle buffer (this may take a while): 1455 of 11760
2021-11-01 08:49:05.657894: I tensorflow/core/kernels/data/shuffle_dataset_op.cc:228] Shuffle buffer filled.
2021-11-01 08:49:05.665031: W tensorflow/core/framework/cpu_allocator_impl.cc:80] Allocation of 1155268608 exceeds 10% of free system memory.
```

Note:
Found 1469 files belonging to 2 classes.

Answer (score 1):

`tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory` returns a `tf.data.Dataset` which is a fancy generator and it yields values as you would expect in python, the only difference being that it yields tensorflow `Tensor` objects so you just need to convert them to `numpy` objects using `numpy()` method

```py
x, y = next(train_data)
x = x.numpy()
y = y.numpy()
```

```py
for x, y in train_data:
   x = x.numpy()
   y = y.numpy()
```

EDIT:

the dataset is batched, meaning you will always read your files in batches. When you defined your `tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory` dataset you probably specified argument `batch_size=29`. If you want to read the entire dataset at once you can use `batch_size=735` but note that tensorflow's `Dataset` is meant to use as a generator from your drive. If you can fit your dataset in your memory you are probably better off reading your files by yourself for example with `tf.keras.utils.load_img`.

Comment: I guess it's not solving the issue, I have posted the screenshot

Comment: @SamarPratapSingh I edited my answer, let me know if you have any more questions

Comment: Now it's showing a memory overflow error.

Comment: Probably because your dataset doesn't fit into your memory, that's why batched dataset generators are used.

Comment: do they occupy less space than numpy arrays?

Comment: the point is that the generator only loads a single batch into the memory, in contrast, if you had your entire dataset in a `numpy` array and wanted to iterate over it you would have to have the array loaded in memory which is not always possible